# How to indicate that a thesis is confidential on the title page using APA style?

Tags: paper-submission

I am currently preparing to submit my thesis/paper to my educational institution and to the company who commissioned the study.

The only entities allowed to read the paper are internals of the university and internals of the company

As my paper is confidential, I am wondering, does APA-style offer any guidelines about how to indicate confidentiality? Are there any do's and don'ts?

Right now, I have CONFIDENTIAL written in bold and red, just above the title on the title page. Like this:

[Example of current title page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIVGU.png)

Comment: I don't think I understand. Where are you submitting a paper to that is confidential?

Comment: Maybe the question becomes clearer if you tell us what you hope to avoid by putting confidential on your paper.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth To the eductional institution I am associated with and to the company that commissioned the study.

Comment: @MaartenBuis The only entities allowed to read the paper are internals of the university and internals of the company.

Comment: Assuming that this expectation of confidentiality is embodied in a contract, then the agreement should specify how to mark material that is under the agreement. At the least I would expect some marking of confidentiality, the parties that distribution is limited to, and perhaps the contract number.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Yes, it is included in a contract. So no APA guidelines on that point?

Comment: Beware that if this is a Bachelor or Master thesis, then that there is often a requirement that the thesis will be made available in the university library. This is often done automatically and anything you write on the title page can easily be ignored. If this is a thesis see your advisor before handing it in to solve this potential conflict.

Comment: APA is intended for scholarly papers, which usually are meant for publication and are not confidential.  So I wouldn't expect APA to have guidelines for this.  I think you can just do anything you think is reasonable, or check with the clients if you think they might care.

Comment: I have edited the question to incorporate some of the comments.

Comment: I'm going to second Nate Eldredge's point: Unless the organization that receives the report has specifically stated a particular format for it, you are free to do whatever you please. You can use APA and a placement of your choice for the CONFIDENTIAL text, or any other format. You use APA style because that's what the journals you submit to want to see, but unless explicitly proscribed, nobody *forces* you to use any particular style for your report.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful additions! It indeed is a (bachelor) thesis. The university explicitly stated it can keep theses confidential if desired. But therefore, it needs to be clear the thesis is confidential in the first place, hence my question. I think I will go with the CONFIDENTIAL text plus a confidentiality clause on the title page